# Help identifying symbol

Tags: identification, symbol

I need help identifying this symbol it's on a solar inverter it's something on the ac input side to me it looks like the burnt component at question is a non polarized capacitor but the symbol doesn't match.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what how these pictures are related. The second is a fuse symbol, but what does that have to do with the melted goo in picture 1?

Comment: Probably a MOV.

Comment: @Unimportant MOV in series with the line?

Comment: That is the symbol under that melted  peice and its actually not a goo it's like a ceramic disk

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/249408/unknown-schematic-symbol-help

Comment: So there is no way to know what value it was because how burnt it is any advice on what I can do because there is no warranty or anything so I'm on my own but I use this every day it's my main source for electricity