# Spot welder circuit questions

Tags: transformer

This is a resistance spot welding circuit with a 5 second timer.

q1.  What is the meaning of the the symbol I highlighted in the green rectangle?

q2.  Should I expect continuity between the two points I highlighted in the red rectangle?

q3. How can I test independently the transformers T1 and T2 in this circuit?

q5. What is the meaning of TD1 in the circuit?

q6. What is the meaning of W in the circuit?

[image: Spot Welder Circuit]

Comment: Looks similar to the symbol in this question - https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/249408/unknown-schematic-symbol-help